# How to use django orm to get all the recipients to a message?

Tags: django, orm

I'm strugling with a complex query that I cannot translate into the django orm.

I'm sending messages. Each message can be sent to recipients and / or groups of recipients. I need to get a list of all the recipients for a given message, and I don't want any duplicates in my list (same user can be in different groups).

Here are my models so far:

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(_('Email'), null=True, blank=True)
    groups = models.ManyToManyField('Group', related_name='members', null=True,
                                    blank=True, verbose_name=_('Groups'))

class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('Name'), max_length=50)


class Message(models.Model):
    body = models.TextField(_('Body'))
    recipients = models.ManyToManyField('contacts.Contact',
                                        null=True, blank=True,
                                        related_name='messages',
                                        verbose_name=_('Recipients'))
    groups = models.ManyToManyField('contacts.Group',
                                    null=True, blank=True,
                                    related_name='messages',
                                    verbose_name=_('Groups'))
```

Can you think of a clever way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Q objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) so that you can select both contacts messaged as part of a group and contacts that were individual recipients in the same queryset.

Then use [`distinct()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct) so that you don't get duplicates.

If you're not familiar with the double underscore notation (e.g. `groups__messages`), then see the docs on [following relationships "backward"](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward).

Putting it all together, you have:

```
message = message.objects.get(id=message_id)
Contact.objects.filter(Q(groups__messages=message)|Q(messages=message)).distinct()
```

You may want to encapsulate the above query in a method on the Message model:

```
class Message(models.Model):
    # field definitions

    def get_recipients(self):
        return Contact.objects.filter(Q(groups__messages=message)|Q(messages=message)).distinct()
```

Then in your view, you can simply write `message.get_recipients()`.

Comment: That was that simple. Thanks (I just changed `group__messages` to `groups__messages`).

Comment: Added the missing _s_ to my answer :)